# always redirect to `/auth/register` on registration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'd like to redirect to `/auth/register_draw` after registration, however it always redirects to  `/auth/register`. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

**AuthController.php**

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->create($request->all());
    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
    Mail::send(
        'auth.emails.register',
        ['user' => $user],
            function (Message $message) use ($user) {
                $message->sender(\Config::get('const.mail.register.from'), \Config::get('const.mail.register.name'))
                        ->to($user->email,  "$user->last_name $user->first_name")
                        ->subject(\Config::get('const.mail.register.subject'));
            }
    );
    return redirect('/auth/register_draw');
}
public function getRegisterDraw()
{
    return view('auth.register_draw');
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::get('auth/register_draw', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegisterDraw');
```

Comment: How does the function getRegisterDraw look like? That might close the loop on whats happening.

Comment: I've written getRegisterDraw. Plz check it.

Comment: Ahh allright, I see you got an answer from codedge, I believe his answer might be more of a help to you :)

Comment: Thx @RobBiermann but it doesnt seem to help ;) Is it possible that your login does not work and Laravel always redirects you back to the page you are coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `return redirect()->route('auth/register_draw');` to redirect to a certain route. Please see *Redirecting To Named Routes* on the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses)

Comment: This is for named routes. In this case you are not using named routes so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To use named routes change the route to

```
Route::get('auth/register_draw', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegisterDraw')->name('register_draw');
```

And use

```
return redirect()->route('register_draw');
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter even if you use a regular route or named route. It should redirect. In your case it's not so their might be some other issue.